# When does getClass().getName() return void?

Tags: java, class

The java documentation for `Class.getName()` says:

> **Returns** the name of the **entity** (`class`, `interface`, `array class`, `primitive type`, or `void`) represented by this `Class` object, as a `String`.

When will it **return** `void`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's `void.class` which represents `void`. `void` is not a type per-se but needs a class to represent it for certain things.

For example:

```
class VoidExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
            VoidExample.class
                .getMethod("main", String[].class)
                    .getReturnType().getName()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It will give you `void` String for class literal for `void` type:

```
Class<Void> clazz = void.class;
System.out.println(clazz.getName());
```

Refer [JLS § 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) for further reading:

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed
>   by a '.' and the token class.
>   [...]
>   The type of void.class (§8.4.5) is `Class<Void>`.

Comment: I've been scouring the JLS and it's funny how little void is mentioned. I can't find anything besides the bit you included (which I didn't find).

Comment: @Radiodef Sometimes it's just that you reach the right topic. That's it. I've been there before, so I knew the exact topic ;)

Comment: Now I do too. :P "Pseudo-type" was the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm good question. Would suggest to hava a look at the source since it is open source. I would say it returns void when the givenClass is of type java.lang.Void.

Comment: Void is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold the type void.class, `Void.TYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [OpenJDK source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getName0%28%29), but unfortunately `GetName()` is a native method, so you'd have to dig deeper to find the exact cases. But I suspect that a practical instance when you'd see this would be if you call [`getReturnType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType%28%29) on a method that returns `void`.